# hikari cp in spring-boot failing to remove connections

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using hikaricp in spring boot as default connection pool. However, the application fails to obtain a connection even when I specify 50 max connections, and I run a jmeter test plan to run 50 threads.
I keep getting 504 Gateway Timeout Error.

My application.properties has:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoreconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=DEBUG
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useLocalSessionState=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cacheServerConfiguration=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.maintainTimeStats=false
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

My code says:

```
try {

            Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(USER_CREDS_QUERY);
            pstmt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
            rst.next();
            user.setUsername(rst.getString(1));
            user.setPassword(rst.getString(2));
            user.setSalt(rst.getString(3));
            rst.close();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            LOG.error("Error in findUser ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

My jmeter test plan has **number of threads set to 50** and **romp-up period set to 15 seconds**.

This works well, when I set the **maximum pool size to 20**, and **request 20 threads**.

Any idea where am I missing?

```
MySQL 5.7
Spring Boot 2.7.9
HikariCP 4.0.3
```

Thanks